# Image Buffering in Visual Studio (Any Version)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Hey there I was wondering if anyone had a solution to the problem I am having when programming in Microsoft Visual Studio with VB.NET.

Basically I want to know how to load images on a form faster. I am creating a 1 form design of a program and whenever I use too many images, it takes >20 seconds to load and becomes really slow. I was looking to see if anyone has managed to find a work around around this however I can't seem to find one.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: where do the images come from?  where are they displayed? details please.  what kind of images (format).  how many? resolution?

Comment: The images come from photoshop, they range in sizes, they are displayed with Picture Boxes on the form, JPEG or PNG format. The amount can vary too, I notice that making use of a colour gradient vastly decreases this amount. Resolutions vary too. One of my friends suggested the use of a double buffer but I have no idea how to implement one, so if there's a fast work around this, I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: If you are talking about just the normal image you want on your form like for buttons and stuff, not something where you are editing the images and need the full resolution original, you should just resize the images so they are the size you need.  Most people will find these huge 20 MegaPixel images and want to use them like icons on thier form. Sure, that loads slow. But, change these to icons or really small images (128X128 or smaller) and it will not slow anything down.

Comment: No no I don't go that overboard, Each image is always less than 1 MB in size. I don't understand how to fix this problem. I'm basically forming an entire program on 1 windows form. How do I increase the speed at which it processes images?. Literally if I use a image as the background, it loads really slow, no matter how big this image is. It's a really annoying problem.

Comment: does the app process the images in some way or are they just eye candy of some sort?